# Special case of the Union closed sets conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, conjectures

If Union closed sets conjecture hold for all finite families, does that imply that it holds for families with some sets repeating twice (no more than that) also? If not, do we have any counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the family of all $8$ subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$. It is union-closed i.e. union of any two sets in the family is also in the family. Each element is contained in $4$ sets. Then let's add one copy of sets $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$. Now there are $3 + 8 = 11$ sets and each element is contained in $1+4 = 5 < {11 \over 2}$ of them. So this is not true for the families with duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Artur Riazanov. Sorry for missing out one vital piece of information. By duplicate, I meant sets occurring twice (no more than that). I will edit the question accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: The same example works as well if we add only one copy of $\{1\},\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$. Now each element is contained in $5$ sets which is less than ${11 \over 2}$.